# Possible to output console result into text file?

Tags: c++, stream

I am required to store the below console data into a text file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b29u.png)

However, the name of the textfile of where the output will be placed in is typed in by the user. I am unable to find a proper way to store all the console data in the requested text file. Since I use width and special spaces I am unsure how to go about doing this.

**My Code:**

```
 if(message == "5"){
                cout << "\n[View Data...]" << endl;
                cout << "filtering criteria:" << optionTwo << endl;
                cout << "sorting criteria:" << optionThree << endl;
                cout << "sorting order:" << optionFour << endl;
                cout << "" << endl;
    




            if(optionTwo == "Point2D"){
    
                std::cout.width(5); std::cout << std::right << "X";
                std::cout.width(6); std::cout << std::right << "Y";
                std::cout.width(9); std::cout << std::right << "Dist.";
                std::cout.width(3); std::cout << std::right << "Fr" ;
                std::cout.width(7); std::cout << std::right << "Origin" << endl;
}
}



if(message == "6"){

            cout << "Please enter filename: " ;
            cin >> message6;


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are sending text into `cout` you are basically writing to a file already, just a system standard one called `stdout`. You simply need to open a different output file stream and send the output the same way.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ofstream out = ofstream("file.txt", ios::out);

out.width(5);
out << std:;right << "X";
```

You do not strictly need to include the `ios::out` since it is the default mode for `ofstream` objects. You can read more at the [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use filestreams for this:

```
std::cin >> message6;           // read file name from the user
std::ofstream file {message6};  // open file with that name
file << "hello world";          // write data to the file
```

Similar to writing data to `cout`, you can use stream modifiers for `file` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of string you're using but, you can use the std::ostream for that:

```
 ofstream myfile;
 cout << "Please enter filename: " ;
 cin >> message6;
 myfile.open (message6);
```

Then instead of using cout, you'd use:

```
myfile << "Your string.\n";
```

But if you want to redirect he actual standard output of the program to a file. You can do it through calling arguments. And that can be set in the execution panel in your IDE or the terminal when the program is called

```
your_program >> output_file.txt
```

Comment: what if I need to print the output as well?

Comment: If you're using the program argument option you could use: ( your_program  | tee output_file.txt ). If you want to do both within the code, use both std::cout and the ofstream.